# Bootstrap Issue Making Buttons Responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I'm having an issue with a calculator app I created. It is located at https://mattfox1388.github.io/Calculator/ if you're interested in seeing my problem. I've been tinkering at my cascading style sheet to find a way to keep my buttons inside the calculator panel. After about 760px width, the buttons will appear in a vertical line that is not good for mobile devices. I've tried using media queries to resize the buttons, changing the bootstrap classes to include row-fluid and many more attempts to keep the buttons looking the same. Not sure what exactly is creating the vertical line for the buttons but any help would be appreciated.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak, .ng-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .btn-sq-sm {
    padding:2px 4px;
    font-size:80%;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius:3px;
  }
}
body{
  font-size:62.5%;
}
html {
  background: url(http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/gray-abstract-background-picture-id481056004?k=6&m=481056004&s=612x612&w=0&h=V5AWzkL1wiYvIPi8ekxcY-KB0k_qSxdGMEqSgII6AU0=) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
p {
  font-size: 24px;
}
#middleDiv{
  position:absolute;
  width: 280px;
  height: 420px;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
  background-color: #BEBEBE;
  border-radius:25px;
  padding:20px;
  padding-top:30px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#displayArea{
  width: 100%;
  height:65px;
  text-align:right;
  font-size:50px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  background-color:black;
  color:#32CD32;
}
.btn-sq-sm {
  width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:-5px;
  text-align:center;
}
.btn-spec{
  width:185px !important;
}
[data-notify="progressbar"] {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 5px;
}
#uni{
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to apply css in media query , you just need to add

```
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button class="btn btn-sq-sm" ng-click="calc.view(7)">
                <p>7</p>
            </button>
          </div>
```

Replace all col-sm-3 with col-xs-3 and will display properly in mobile also

Comment: Thank you for the help sir. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used **`col-sm-3`** which works till **`width 768px`**, after that it becomes 100% width.

So try to use **`col-xs-3`** instead of **`col-sm-3`**

> ***[More help on bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options)***

```
<div class="row">
  <!--first button-->
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <button class="btn btn-sq-sm" ng-click="calc.clearStacks()"><p>C</p></button>
  </div>
  <!-- second buttons-->
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <button class="btn btn-sq-sm"><p id="uni">`</p></button>
  </div>
  <!-- third buttons-->
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <button class="btn btn-sq-sm" ng-click="calc.addOperation('/')"><p>/</p></button>
  </div>
  <!-- fourth buttons-->
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <button class="btn btn-sq-sm" ng-click="calc.addOperation('*')"><p>x</p></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help with my question. Thank you.